# Threads with fifo

Tags: c, multithreading, ipc, fifo

I have the application below where thread 1 reads from a file and put to FIFO, then thread 2 reads that FIFO and process the data and send to network socket, thread 3 is receiving data from network socket and then save the result to file2 but sometimes the received data has to be re-processed by thread2, so the question is what's the best thing to do? Do I need to send to FIFO again? or have another fifo between thread 3 and thread 2? or neither ?

File1 --> thread 1 --> FIFO --> thread 2 --> network socket

network socket --> thread 3 --> file2

BTW, the above is a sample of what I have, the actual program will have many threads read from FIFO and send to the network, not sure if using FIFO this way will cause latency or will be a bottleneck.

Appreciate you help.

Comment: Under what conditions does the data need to be re-processed?  Is it something that can be detected by Thread 2 in the first place?

Comment: Thread 2 has infinite loop, it crunches whatever is there in the fifo, so no thread 2 doesn't detect anything

Comment: what I'm afraid is that there are more that one that reads from from FIFO, not sure if that will be a bottleneck

Comment: Sure, but what does "reprocessing" mean in this context?  Do you mean "sending the data to thread 3 again?".  And under what conditions do you need to reprocess?

Answer (score 0):

Ummm,

Is there a particular reason why *select* system call which will monitor an array of file and socket descriptors is not being used? This could simplify the code as shown [here](http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2008/03/09/using-select-on-a-fifo/).

Are you using pthreads or something like boost thread library...

Are these threads indeed different processes... or is this all one program where you use pthread_cond_wait() ?

Comment: I'm using pthread, all in one program and I'm not using pthread_cond_wait()

Comment: Usually, you use a mutex to guard a condition_variable. Are these multiple processes? Like I asked?...If just a single process, then no _mmap_ a file... use pthread_mutex_init()

Comment: The reason I'm not using lock is because I'm sending less than pipe_buff so the sync is gonna be done by the kernel, and no this is one process

Comment: Is pipe_buf an actual FIFO created by **mkdev** or **mknod**? You should according to <a href="http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2008/03/09/using-select-on-a-fifo/">this</a> open the FIFO for reading, that solves the problem with _select_.

Comment: I'm opening the fifo with o_nonblock option, Actually I don't have problem in this part or with syncing, even if there is one let's ignore it.

Comment: No, but the article I found suggests opening the FIFO as _rw_, if that's allowed and this makes _select_ practical. _Select_ will multitask the FIFO, and sockets and _file descriptors_ together and feed them as a virtual queue...